# how to get the reference of struct soap inherited in C++ Proxy/Service class

Tags: c++, gsoap

Currently I convert sample code in gsoap_distribution/samples/magic into C++ client code using soapProxy .cpp and C++ server code using soapService.cpp, which are generated by "soapcpp2 -i magic.h".

I have found problems when converting some functions that require soap reference as follows:
soap_new_matrix(&soap, -1);
soap_print_fault_location(&soap, stderr);

In my understading, Service/Proxy Classes (generated by "soapcpp2 -i" options) inherit the struct soap. Is there some way to get the reference to struct soap from C++ Proxy/Service class object?

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Dear  Lawrence Aiello,
Thanks for your interest. I'm newbe to stackoverflow.
Could you tell me how to unpload source codes at stackoverflow ?

Comment: I found alternative solution. soapcpp2 -j option generates proxy/service class with share soap object member variable instead of inheritance.
For your information,
-i generate C++ service proxies and objects inherited from soap struct
-j generate C++ service proxies and objects that share a soap struct

Answer (score 0):

Because the proxy and service classes are inherited from the `soap` context class with option `-i` for soapcpp2, you can simply pass a pointer to your proxy or service objects to these functions. For example:

```
#include "soapmagicProxy.h" // generated by soapcpp2 -i magic.h
#include "magic.nsmap"      // XML namespace mapping table

magicProxy service("http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/magicserver.cgi");
matrix *matrix = soap_new_matrix(&service);
service.magic(7, matrix);
...
service.destroy();
```